# Dependency error while using LOOKUPVALUE() in Power BI with two foreign keys

Tags: foreign-keys, powerbi, lookup

I am stuck with a very simple (yet frustrating problem). I have table1 with the following columns :

```
id1  id2   title1                  title2
------------------------------------------------
 1    2    A great headline        ERROR
 1    3    A great headline        ERROR
```

title1 & title2 are column populated from table2 with the LOOKUPVALUE() function. table2 looks like this :

```
id   title
--------------------------
 1   A great headline
 2   Another great headline
 3   A third great headline
```

I've put a many-to-one relationship between table1[id1] and table2[id] and managed to get values for table1[title1] using this formula :

```
LOOKUPVALUE(table2[title]; table2[id]; table1[id1])
```

However, when I try to populate table1[title2], I get a circular dependency error.

I tried both those functions :

```
LOOKUPVALUE(table2[title]; table2[id]; table1[id2]) -> Look id2 into id and return title

LOOKUPVALUE(table1[title1]; table1[id1]; table1[id2]) -> Look id2 into id1 and return title1
```

Could someone suggest a work-around for this problem?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated your example with no errors. Check the direction of your one to many relationship.

I setup two relationships. Note that only one can be "Active".

[image]

[image]